# R shinyFiles : Warning: Error in [: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable [No stack trace available]

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I want to use shiny to select a local directory and output the files in selected directory.

But I got the following error, what is the problem?

> Warning: Error in [: object of type 'closure' is not subsettable [No stack trace available]

Thanks a lot.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFiles)

ui <- shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
  shinyDirButton('folder', 'Folder select', 'Please select a folder', FALSE)
))
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  volumes = getVolumes()
  shinyDirChoose(input, 'folder', roots= volumes)
})

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The famous error message "Object of type `closure` is not subsettable" indicates that you are trying to subset a function. In your case the issue is that `getVolumes()` returns a function which when called returns a vector of available volumes. To solve your issue change your call of `shinyDirChoose` like so:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  volumes = getVolumes()
  shinyDirChoose(input, 'folder', roots = volumes())
})
```